# Syntax profile close to dosini but with extra highlighting between quotes

Tags: vimrc, syntax-highlighting, colorscheme, syntax

Unfortunately I've to work with a custom and weird file format every day. To make my life in Vim easier, I've tried several syntax settings and 'dosini' comes very close.

However, the text in between single or double quotes is not highlighted. My life would become much better if that were the case.

Now, I have tried to find a syntax from another filetype that might match my needs. But I cannot find it and there are way to many to check one by one. Perhaps you know of one that suits my needs?

Alternatively I have been looking at extending an existing syntax configuration. Unfortunately that was a tough cookie for me. But maybe this could still be a valid idea.

Might anybody here be able to help me accomplish my goal?  It is much appreciated!

Simple file example:

[image: visual representation]

Also notice the equation highlight. I'm using peachpuff color scheme.

Comment: seems to highlight strings for me.  have you tried different colorschemes?

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! Please [edit] your question to give an example of the file format you wish to highlight, and any other information you can share. Otherwise it is very hard to know what you need.

Comment: Thanks for your time Mass and @d-ben-knoble . I've added the example in my question. It comes down to a weird mix between a .ini file and a programming file.

Comment: The syntax under `[PSEUDO_CODE]` looks more like C or Java or such than an INI file... (Except for the single quoted strings.) Wouldn't it be easier to start from C or such and then add support for the `[...]` lines? Making a syntax from scratch is not *too* hard... If you're willing to put in the time, maybe look for some tutorials online on how to do that?

Comment: Indeed @filbranden . Whichever route is easiest. Unfortunately I do not have the time nor the know-how, which is why I turned to StackExchange in the hope that somebody might have an easy solution for me. But of course I do understand if it is not that easy, and it is not my intention to have other do the hard work for me. Was just hoping that somebody might be able to provide and easy way to accommodate my request.